# Why is there no assets directory in my rails 3.0.1 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm new to ruby on rails so i'm using the book [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) to learn from. The problem I'm having is that when the directory structure of my app is built. I do not have this directory :

`app/assets`

Of course I can create this directory structure manually, but I'm following the book exactly and this structure should be generated with my app (to the best of my understanding). Am I missing something simple?

```
NOTE: I'm using ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

rails --version
Rails 3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to update to the latest version of Rails to be able to use the asset pipeline. It exists starting in 3.1.0

If you are using rvm:

```
gem install rails
```

Put sudo in front of that if you are not.

One other thing to note is that if you generate the app with Ruby 1.9.2, you'll need to use at least that version in production.

Comment: Is there a way to make 3.1.0 the default?

Comment: once you install Rails 3.1 when you do `rails new <appname>` then it would use Rails 3.1 unless you explicitly pass a version number to the rails command.

Comment: Thanks everyone! 3.1 is NOT 3.0.1!!

Comment: I don't believe "gem install rails" is related to RVM at all, or is it ?

Comment: I'm a nooby @LePad so I don't have and answer for that.